# Regex to Match an alpha numeric combination only once

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have an alphanumeric string(M-T-D-S-F1-F2), I need to make sure that a combination of alnum (F1) exists only once in the string.

Example String: `M-T-D-S-F1-F2`

The regex i am using is `/^[^F1]*F1?[^F1]*$/`

```
M-T-D-S-F1 -> Matches
M-T-D-S-F1 F -> Doesn't match (Since it is not matching F1 literally)
M-T-D-S-F1 F2 -> Doesn't match
```

The problem is the regex fails with F2 present. I need to consider F1 as a combination and match literally.

How can i do that?

Comment: Just to clarify, you'd like to match exactly `F1` only once in a word (with dashes)? i.e. These two will pass: `M-T-D-S-F1`, `M-T-D-S-F1 F2`; but these two will fail `M-T-D-S-F1-F1`, `M-T-D-S-F1-F9`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make sure there are no 2 `F1`  as whole words in a string, use a simple `/\bF1\b/`  regex and check the `.count` of matches. If there are more than 1, the string is invalid, else, it is valid:

```
String s = "M-T-D-S-F1-F2";
def m = s =~ /\bF1\b/;
if (m.count > 1) {
    println("FAIL!");
} else {
    println("VALID");
}
```

See a [Groovy demo online](http://ideone.com/QSkP1G).

A pure regex solution is possible, but is inefficient:

```
/^(?!.*\bF1\b.*\bF1\b)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VhST8o/1).

It matches the start of a string, and then the negative lookahead (`(?!...)`) fails any string if there is a whole word `F1` after zero or more chars (`.*`) followed with 0+ chars and again a whole word `F1`.

Comment: Both the solutions here can be easily adapted to require `F1` at least once. 1) `m.count == 1` and 2) `/^(?!.*\bF1\b.*\bF1\b).*\bF1\b/`